# Unable to start the process with helper.py in python pysys

Tags: python, windows

```
import sys, os, os.path, re, string, time, thread, logging, copy, math, stat

from pysys import log
from pysys.constants import *

from pysys.process.helper import ProcessWrapper

def __stringToUnicode( s):
        """ Converts a unicode string or a utf-8 bit string into a unicode string. 

        """
        if isinstance(s, unicode):
            return s
        else:
            return unicode(s, "utf8")
environ ={}
for key in environ: environ[__stringToUnicode(key)] = __stringToUnicode(environ[key])

process = ProcessWrapper("C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox", arguments=None, environs=environ, workingDir=None, state=FOREGROUND, timeout=None, stdout=None, stderr=None)
process.start()
```

I am getting this error..

```
  process = ProcessWrapper("notepad", arguments=None, environs=environ, workingDir=None, state=FOREGROUND, timeout=None, stdout=None, stderr=None)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pysys\process\plat-win32\helper.py", line 105, in __init__
    for a in self.arguments: log.debug("  argument     : %s", a)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I am new to pysys. please help me out.

Comment: Your traceback doesn't match your code.

Answer (score 1):

The below works for me when I try it - not sure if the issue was in the unicode translation.

```
import logging
from pysys.constants import *
from pysys import stdoutHandler
from pysys.process.helper import ProcessWrapper

stdoutHandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

command="\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe"
process = ProcessWrapper(command, arguments=[], environs=os.environ, workingDir=os.getcwd(), state=BACKGROUND, timeout=None)
process.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, `ProcessWrapper()` expects `arguments` to be an iterable (a list or a tuple would do).

Instead of `None`, use `()` (an empty tuple).

Note however, that `workingDir` *should* be set to a string. Use `os.getcwd()` for a sane default. `timeout` also has to be set, to an integer count of seconds to wait. I guess 60 seconds (a full minute) is as good as anything.

You can *omit* the `stdout` and `stderr` arguments and leave those at their defaults:

```
process = ProcessWrapper("C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox", arguments=() environs=environ, workingDir=os.getcwd(), state=FOREGROUND, timeout=60)
```